# How do I format a date as an acceptable file name?

Tags: powershell, foreach

I'm working on defining a date variable, but I need the date to be able to be used as a file name. Because of that, I need to replace a few special characters grabbed by Get-Date and replace them with underscores and periods.

`$date = Get-Date -Format G | foreach {$_ -replace ":", "."}`

Currently, that replaces all the :'s in the datetime, but leaves /. How can I use -replace to replace multiple things?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put all characters you want to replace in a character group

```
PS> Get-Date -Format G | foreach {$_ -replace "[:\./]", "_"}
6_5_2013 3_50_44 PM
```

An easier way would be to use the -Format operator:

```
PS> Get-Date -Format 'MM_dd_yyyy HH_mm_ss tt'
06_05_2013 15_52_09 PM
```